# Passing a png image to a numpy array, what is the 4th column last dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, png

I exported a png image to a python numpy array.

```
import numpy
import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 Im=Image.opne('file.png')
 arr=numpy.array(Im).reshape(Im.size[1],Im.size[0],4)
plt.imshow(arr)
plt.show()
```

Now, in books I found reshape of png using 3 channels, which does not work for me. I had to use 4.

```
>>> Im.shape
(401, 601, 4)
```

I can visualize the Red channel :

```
ImR=Im[:,:,0]
```

Similar for Green and Blue. The last one give me a white screen.

I managed to remove it:

```
Im4=Im[:,:,:-1]
```

and now:

```
>>> Im4.shape
(401, 601, 3)
```

I can visualize the image as before removing this 4th column

My question is: what is this 4th column for in PNG?

Comment: You image might be composed of RGB and A, A being the [alpha](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/alpha_channel.html) channel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the PNG had an alpha channel, the fourth column would be alpha.  Since visualizing that channel gave you all-white, all of the alphas are maxval (255 if your samples are 8-bit) which means all pixels are opaque.